# How to deny root mariadb user from sudo?

Tags: sudo, root, mariadb

My root@localhost user has the password, but a sudo-user can access from command line without password, is it possibile to disable this sudo command line access?

Comment: Since you're seemingly concerned about security, this one(vs others) has more arguments on why/why not to use the configurations https://superuser.com/questions/735172/how-to-prevent-sudo-users-from-running-specific-commands/735286

Comment: I simply don't want to share my database structure to all sudo users.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid entering with sudo and that only root can enter, only recommended for your database installed locally and not in production, you could use mysql_secure_installation with a password for root.

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

With this command you go through a wizard that will ask you different questions. You must tell it to keep the root user, with a password. and so you could access through without sudo.

```
mysql -u root -p
```